# Web server behind IIS on one machine is not able to access files on other machine?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2003

What all permissions or setting Or steps need to be done so that Web application behind IIS on one machine is able to access the files/directory on the other machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An application pool in IIS has an identity (user) that runs the web site in question. This identity needs access to the files on the other machine. The identity used is often NT Authority\Network Service. So this is basically the account that needs access to the files. The Network Service account of a computer called `ComputerA` is called `ComputerA$` when referenced on another computer. So on your file server you need to make sure that `ComputerA$` (or your equivalent) has access to the files.

Comment: When i am trying to add {MachineName}$ on that machine it says "An object named "DOMAIN\{MachineName}$" cannot be found. Check the selected object types and location for accuracy and ensure that you typed the object name correctly, or remove this object from the selection." Though i found some existing combinations for {MachineName}$ in the list for same machine. Am i missing something ?

Comment: @Anil Namde, make sure you have selected the right "location". It must be the domain and not local computer.

Comment: I added UserName then the MachineName too then it got automatically reflected as {MachineName}$. How is that ?